# consuming REST API with C#

Tags: c#, http, rest

I'm very new to C# and want to learn how to make HTTP requests. I want to start really simple, although that is currently evading me. I want to just perform a GET on, say, google.com. I created a command line application, and have this code. Not sure at all which usings are required.

I tested it by writing to the console, and it doesn't get past the response. Can somebody please clue me in? I'm looking to do some simple curl type stuff to test an existing API. Thank you for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace APItest
{
    class testClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://www.google.com";

            Console.WriteLine(url);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Does `request.GetResponse()` hang? That is, are you sure the program is not just waiting for the keystroke in `ReadKey()`?

Comment: Yeah it hangs at the GetResponse. I had a Console.WriteLine in there after just to test (which doesn't appear above for clarity).

Comment: If you're fine with using `async..await`, the `HttpClient` API might be more straightforward: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx (E.g. you just call `var responseBody = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url);` Especially since it seems like you intend to use  `System.Threading.Tasks` already.

Comment: Do you think that is some environment issue e.g. proxy...? If you are in windows environment, have you try to run fiddler while you are running the code and see if there is any request being capture?

Comment: I seem to get the response when I'm at work. When I was on the hotel network it was not working for me. Any ideas why that might be? Thank you.

Comment: @allstar Proxy settings could have caused it to behave differently on the hotel's network. If their network was behind a proxy and your work network wasn't (or was behind a different one) that might have blocked the connection. You would need to set the proxy property of the `HttpRequest` object I believe. An example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I would look into using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) instead which was created to make calling rest API's much easier in .net 4. It also supports `async` and `await`.

You can call it like this (using async):

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetGoogle() {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

    var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse for consuming web services in .Net.  [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `WebClient` class. It has a rich set of methods to do most HTTP related tasks, link to the full documentation below

[WebClient MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the response:

`var stream = response.GetResponseStream();`

Thenyou have your stream and do what you need with it.
[`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)

Comment: Problem is I can't even get past the response line. If I add Console.WriteLine("Testing"); after the response, it is never written to the console.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine... gets past the request and down to the readKey...